# usar o implode PHP

Tags: php

Estou precisando colocar o resultado dessa forma: valorA,valorB,valorC. Estou usando o código abaixo:

```
$valor = "valorA";
$valor .= "valorB";
$valor .= "valorC";

$array = array($valor);

echo implode(",",$array);
```

Só que usando dessa forma, não estou conseguindo. As valores das variáveis $valor, vem através de um checkbox em HTML.

Comment: Poste o form também, para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Olá, existem várias formas de criar `arrays` e a que acabaste de usar aí não é obviamente das melhores ou correta sequer, alguém respondeu a tua pergunta, mas não entendi ao certo porque queres algo assim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O conteúdo final de `$valor` é uma string contendo `valorAvalorBvalorC`, e não um array.

Você precisa fazer assim:

```
$valor   = array();
$valor[] = "valorA";
$valor[] = "valorB";
$valor[] = "valorC";

echo implode(",",$valor);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$varArray   = array();

foreach($_POST['NAME_CHECKBOX'] as $item){
   $varArray[] = $item;
}

echo implode(",", $varArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Baseado apenas no código que você postou:

```
$valor = "valorA";
$valor .= "valorB";
$valor .= "valorC";
```

Poderia ser alterado para te dar o resultado desejado:

```
$valor = "valorA";
$valor .= ",valorB";
$valor .= ",valorC";
```

Agora, se você está precisando mesmo de um array, vai ter que inicilizar um array primeiro, e encher com os valores (basicamente o que o @RodrigoRigotti respondeu!):

```
$valor = array();
$valor[] = "valorA";
$valor[] = "valorB";
$valor[] = "valorC";
```

E daí dá pra usar o implode:

```
echo implode(",",$valor);
```